# Почему окно Qt обрезается

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Написал приложение на C++ через Qt, на моём ПК и паре тестовых окно отображается корректно, но у одного из пользователей оно обрезается. Прикладываю фото того как отображается окно у пользователя и фото настроек QMainWindow. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?
[image: QMainWindow]
[image: Окно программы]

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело в скейлинге винды. На 100% работает нормально, на увеличенном скейлинге не адаптируется

Comment: Проверял, скейлинг никак не влияет

Comment: Тогда как будто бы нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример, без него пока других идей нет

Comment: похоже что окно свойств просто откреплено. попробуйте двойным кликом по заголовку примагнитить его

Comment: В приложении только одно окно и всё остальное это виджеты на нём, по сути обрезается сам MainWindow